# Using Conditionals when homepage is a page and blog is /blog

Tags: php

I am setting up a blog with a static front page (name: Front Page, slug: front-page) and the blog on a page named "Blog" with the slug "blog".

What I want to do is have my site title be inside and h1 element when the page is post listing such as /blog, but then be inside and h6 element when it it is a page, single post, etc.

Right now my condition looks as follows:

```
<?php if ( is_page( 'blog' ) ) : ?>
    <h1>POST LISTING</h1>
<?php else : ?>
    <h1>NOT POST LISTING</h1>
<?php endif; ?>
```

When I pull the sit up, everything displays the NOT POST LISTING text, even /blog.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is_home` is the check you need to use if the page is set to be the blog page in settings > reading

```
<?php
if(is_home()) {
 // do something
} else {
 // do something
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you. I figured it was something simple. In my head I was confusing is_home() for is_front_page().